# Should AutoMapper also be used as a Re-Shape mapping tool

Tags: c#, viewmodel, automapper, dto

I know AutoMapper is just to map properties between 2 objects.

Automapper is not for reshaping data this must be programmed in my opinion.

I have a `PeriodDTO.IEnumerable<Period>` which needs to be reshaped into a `PeriodListViewModel.List<CellViewModel>`.

Each `CellViewModel` holds a `List<RowViewModel>`

This is no 1 to 1 mapping not and I guess maybe this should not be mapped - because its not possible -

```
public class PeriodRequest
    {
        public IEnumerable<Period> Periods { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<DateTime> Weeks { get; set; }
    }

public class PeriodListViewModel
{       
    public PeriodListViewModel(IEnumerable<Period> periods)
    {
        CellViewModels = new List<CellViewModel>();
        var groupedPeriods = periods.GroupBy(p => p.LessonNumber).OrderBy(p => p.Key).ToList();
        foreach (var groupedPeriod in groupedPeriods)
        {
            var cellViewModel = new CellViewModel();
            CellViewModels.Add(cellViewModel);
            foreach (var period in groupedPeriod)
            {
                var rowViewModel = new RowViewModel();
                rowViewModel.Content = period.Content;
                rowViewModel.SchoolclassCode = period.SchoolclassCode;
                rowViewModel.DayName = period.LessonDate.ToShortDateString();
                rowViewModel.DayIndex = (int)period.LessonDate.DayOfWeek;
                rowViewModel.LessonNumber = period.LessonNumber;
                cellViewModel.Rows.Add(rowViewModel);
            }
        }
    }
    public List<CellViewModel> CellViewModels { get; set; }
}

public class CellViewModel
    {
        public CellViewModel()
        {
            Rows = new List<RowViewModel>();
        }
        public List<RowViewModel> Rows { get; set; }
    }

public class RowViewModel
    {
        public string DayName { get; set; }
        public string SchoolclassCode { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public int DayIndex { get; set; }
        public int LessonNumber { get; set; }
    }

public class Period
    {
        public int PeriodId { get; set; }
        public DateTime LessonDate { get; set; }
        public int LessonNumber { get; set; }
        public string SchoolclassCode { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public int SchoolyearId { get; set; }
        public Schoolyear Schoolyear { get; set; }
...
}
```

At the moment the PeriodListViewModel can be easily unit tested. I am asking myself now how can AutoMapper make the situation even better?

Comment: Do you mean "ReSharper", or "Re-Shape"?

Comment: I think "Reshaper" means Re-Shape. I too read it as ReSharper.

Comment: changed the title now its RE-SHAPE :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you don't have a trivial 1:1 Mapping from `IEnumerable<Period>` to `List<CellViewModel>`, you can still derive some value from Automapper by using it only at the place where you get class-to-class contact, which in your example is between `Period` and `RowViewModel`.

With this in mind, you can also make better use of LINQ and get everything done in one sweeping motion, provided you set up the projections that require re-shaping from `Period` to `RowViewModel`.

Here's a console code example that demonstrates exactly that. Note that we're using Automapper's notion of resolver classes via `ValueResolve<TSource,TDestination>` do the re-shaping, and I've added an extra constructor to `CellViewModel` to accept an `IEnumerable<RowViewModel>`, which helps improve our declarations.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using AutoMapper;

namespace GroupingMapping
{
    public class PeriodRequest
    {
        public IEnumerable<Period> Periods { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<DateTime> Weeks { get; set; }
    }

    public class RowViewModel
    {
        public string DayName { get; set; }
        public string SchoolclassCode { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public int DayIndex { get; set; }
        public int LessonNumber { get; set; }
    }

    public class Period
    {
        public int PeriodId { get; set; }
        public DateTime LessonDate { get; set; }
        public int LessonNumber { get; set; }
        public string SchoolclassCode { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public int SchoolyearId { get; set; }
        // No definition provided for Schoolyear
        //public Schoolyear Schoolyear { get; set; }
    }

    public class CellViewModel
    {
        public CellViewModel()
        {
            Rows = new List<RowViewModel>();
        }

        public CellViewModel(IEnumerable<RowViewModel> rowVMSet)
        {
            Rows = new List<RowViewModel>(rowVMSet);
        }

        public List<RowViewModel> Rows { get; set; }
    }

    public class PeriodListViewModelEx
    {
        public PeriodListViewModelEx(IEnumerable<Period> periods)
        {
            CellViewModels = new List<CellViewModel>(periods
                .GroupBy(p => p.LessonNumber)
                .OrderBy(grp => grp.Key)
                .Select(grp =>
                {
                    return new CellViewModel(
                        grp.Select(p => { return Mapper.Map<Period, RowViewModel>(p); }));
                }));
        }
        public List<CellViewModel> CellViewModels { get; set; }
    }

    class DateTimeToDateNameResolver : ValueResolver<DateTime, string>
    {
        protected override string ResolveCore(DateTime source)
        {
            return source.ToShortDateString();
        }
    }

    class DateTimeToDayOfWeekResolver : ValueResolver<DateTime, int>
    {
        protected override int ResolveCore(DateTime source)
        {
            return (int)source.DayOfWeek;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<Period, RowViewModel>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.DayName, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<DateTimeToDateNameResolver>().FromMember(src => src.LessonDate))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.DayIndex, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<DateTimeToDayOfWeekResolver>().FromMember(src => src.LessonDate));

            Period[] periods = new Period[3];

            periods[0] = new Period { PeriodId = 1, LessonDate = DateTime.Today.Add(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0)), LessonNumber = 101, SchoolclassCode = "CS101", Content = "Intro to CS", SchoolyearId = 2013 };
            periods[1] = new Period { PeriodId = 2, LessonDate = DateTime.Today.Add(new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0, 0)), LessonNumber = 101, SchoolclassCode = "CS101", Content = "Intro to CS", SchoolyearId = 2013 };
            periods[2] = new Period { PeriodId = 3, LessonDate = DateTime.Today.Add(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0)), LessonNumber = 102, SchoolclassCode = "EN101", Content = "English (I)", SchoolyearId = 2013 };

            PeriodListViewModelEx pvModel = new PeriodListViewModelEx(periods);

            Console.WriteLine("CellViews: {0}", pvModel.CellViewModels.Count);

            foreach (CellViewModel cvm in pvModel.CellViewModels)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} items in CellViewModel Group", cvm.Rows.Count);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Inspecting CellViewModel Rows");
            foreach (CellViewModel cvm in pvModel.CellViewModels)
            {
                foreach (RowViewModel rvm in cvm.Rows)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("  DayName: {0}", rvm.DayName);
                    Console.WriteLine("  SchoolclassCode: {0}", rvm.SchoolclassCode);
                    Console.WriteLine("  Content: {0}", rvm.Content);
                    Console.WriteLine("  DayIndex: {0}", rvm.DayIndex);
                    Console.WriteLine("  LessonNumber: {0}", rvm.LessonNumber);
                    Console.WriteLine("  -");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("--");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First thanks for the code. Now I have 2 questions: 1.) Why the ValueResolver classes which seem overhead to me. In my PeriodProfile.cs class I can easily map the Period.LessonDate to the RowViewModel.DayIndex by mapping those properties with a (int)Period.LessonDate.DayOfWeek. For the ToShortDateString its the same 1:1 mapping by just using a ToShortDateString. No ValueResolver needed in my opinion. So What you have changed is "just" put a Period/RowViewModel Map into my PeriodListViewModel. I rather thought of outsourcing all logic into a profile class but this is not possible?

Comment: This is not part of the solution but it would really interest me as you already know this question well how would you deal with the opposite way? From client to the server send an already grouped PeriodListViewModel and map it to an IEnumerable<Period>? There I can not put in de-group/flatten code into my constructor of the PeriodListViewModel. Where would that logic be?

Comment: The `ValueResolver` classes are a bit of overhead; but if you're using Automapper, that should already be a tradeoff you're willing to make in the hopes of spending less time writing and verifying code. Also, while you can write adapters manually on a class-relation basis, using Automapper's facilities allows you to write just the one line of mapping code when you need the projection. As many things are in programming, you can perform the same action in many ways; but Automapper's main advantage is the ability to be brief when performing projection, at the cost of being verbose in preparation.

Comment: For the reverse, you could write a model that contains a `IEnumerable<Period>` that can be instantiated from a `PeriodListViewModel` or `IEnumerable<CellViewModel>` (note that `List<>` can be treated as `IList<>` which derives from `IEnumerable<>`). One problem, though, is that your `RowViewModel` doesn't have close correspondence to a `Period`. If this isn't a problem (perhaps you only intend to make new `Period` items from the partial information in a set of `RowViewModel`s), you can still use Automapper as a means to project data back, just setup a reverse mapping as you see fit.

Comment: If you still remember my last sentence from the init question:"At the moment the PeriodListViewModel can be easily unit tested". I think this got worse now. I use MOQ for mocking which can not mock static classes/methods. That means I can not unit test my PeriodListViewModel with your solution except the mapping period process from Automapper but not the rest. Normally I use the IMappingEngine from Automapper that can be mocked easily BUT I would have to inject the imappingengine instance into my PeriodListViewModel uhm... again more efforts...

Comment: your solution has lots of more code then and coupling for just have an automechanism of copying 5 properties. Please tell me still a valid reason for using your solution with my corrections?

Comment: I suppose I'm missing other details that are not shown here for the `PeriodListViewModel`. Could you explain what makes this solution untestable? Also, I agree that there isn't much benefit to using Automapper for only 5 properties; the benefits by LoC measure don't accrue until you have two projections to cover between compatible classes/interfaces; it appears to me that you might only get value out of mappings into `RowViewModel`s and `RowViewModel` to `RowViewModel`.

Comment: I posted all code. No hidden details or surprises ;-) "Untestable" => With your solution I would use a static Mapper.Map class/method. When I test the PeriodListViewModel  then I can not mock the Mapper.Map as its static so the unit test will turn into an integration test. Sometimes questions like these from me have no 100% solutions or I will not follow/apply them but that does not mean I have not learned anything from them and for this you get the accepted answer :)

Comment: Aha, valid point. Automapper is quite well tested; most would skip testing the mapping feature or would just check the results after assignment. If you want tests to cover customized behavior (`ValueResolver`s, etc.), you could cover those in separate tests targeting only the assumptions that rely on features in Automapper.

Answer (score 0):

For a few months I primarily used AutoMapper for creating my view models from my entity models, basically what you are doing there.  I have used AutoMapper to flatten and unflatten very complex models.

I personally wouldn't do it in a constructor of a view model though.  The reason being is that you might have different sources of a PeriodListViewModel.  The idea is that once you have your mappers created/configured, at will you can do `Mapper.Map<PeriodViewModel(collectionOfCells);` or `Mapper.Map<PeriodViewModel(periodEntity);` depending on what the situation calls for.  **This way neither your PeriodViewModels nor your Period class have any knowledge or relation to each other.**  If the Period class changes in response to database changes, then you just tweak your automapper mappings to accomodate the change, leaving PeriodViewModel class unchanged, and thus not having to touch any of the views which use it.  Vice versa as well.

Even if I wasn't using automapper, I'd still have static helper methods do the copying of entity models to view models.  Something as simple as a View Model should have a simple default constructor to make it easy to use.

However, I will say that doing complex mappings in AutoMapper is quite challenging, and debugging sometimes daunting.  Many times I found myself in another developer's office helping them understand the chain of mappings that was occuring.  As it's name implies, as it delves into child objects/collections/navigation properties, it automatically maps them, and thus alot of things are happening **implicitely**, which is really difficult to debug.  You basically have to do alot of mental visualization of these object graphs and then go hunt down the mapping that you *think* is being used.  Some of the mapping options don't allow multi-line anonymous methods, and thus you can't put a breakpoint or extra logging code.

As a developer often pushing data from the database to the frontend, AutoMapper is pretty much exactly what I had always dreamed of, but after using it for a few months, I probably would avoid using it to translate object graphs more than 2 levels deep. For what you're doing in your example, I think AutoMapper would be fine.

**Update:**

I would keep querying and mapping seperate. First query to get back my entities, because I might need to pass in parameters to where criteria as well.  Then the resulting List from ToList is passed to automapper.map to convert the Period entities to PeriodViewModel's.  In your case you have a nested collection because of the group by.  You could either create a mapping from a collection of Periods(groupedPeriod) to a single CellViewModel, then

```
foreach (var groupOfPeriods in groupedPeriods)
{
            Mapper.Map<CellViewModel>(groupOfPeriods );
            CellViewModels.Add(cellViewModel);
}
```

I believe this will work(given you create a mapping for it, because an IGrouping implement IEnumerable and in this case TElement is a Period.

The other option, is instead of creating a mapping from IEnumerable to CellViewModel, is to isntead create a mapping from Period to RowViewModel and do this:

```
...
foreach (var groupedPeriod in groupedPeriods)
{
    var cellViewModel = new CellViewModel();
    CellViewModels.Add(cellViewModel);
    foreach (var period in groupedPeriod)
    {
        var rowViewModel = Mapper.Map<RowViewModel>(period); 
        cellViewModel.Rows.Add(rowViewModel);    
    }
}
...
```

That second option would probably be the simpler option, as the mapping will be simpler.  I think the first option might be more difficult to maintain/debug, since too much "magic" would be baked into the CreateMap.

I don't have any of my old auto mapper code handy though, so I can't give you accurate code examples on how to configure the actual CreateMap parts, but the second option should be fairly straightforward.

Also, since automapper understands how to map lists of things just by you telling it how to map a single item, you could probably get away with this:

```
...
foreach (var groupedPeriod in groupedPeriods)
{
    var cellViewModel = new CellViewModel();
    CellViewModels.Add(cellViewModel);
    cellViewModel.Rows = Mapper.Map<List<RowViewModel>>(groupedPeriod);
}
...
```

It depends on exactly what the type of the collection `Rows` is, if it is not a `List<RowViewModel>` then change that part so that AutoMapper creates the correct type of collection.  See for more information on mapping lists: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Lists-and-arrays

Comment: I cant get my head around the point how I can include the Linq groupby/order stuff in the AutoMapper Profile class OR am I on the wrong track and the Linq stuff should stay inside the PeriodListViewModel. Its mind boggling to find the way how to map it if it can easily be programmed... I can not image somehow how this can work. Could you go on with a little code sample that is working not just a rough hint? Your above description Mapper PeriodViewModel(collectionOfCell) should actually be Mapper<Period,CellViewModel> A Period has a cell, but a CellVM has not the propertiers of a Period...??!!

Comment: therefore I can not imagine how I could mape that. In my case the ctor injection is totally fine. Different sources of a PeriodListViewModel? Can you explain that further please?

Comment: I have added some more details and examples to the answer.  Time for me to get back to work :)  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your time and efforts. As I told meklarian not literally but when I write double code just that automapper covers all then I stick to my own former testable solution for the sake of KISS :)